# GoogleApiClient keeps GPS radio on

Tags: android, gps, location, google-api-client, fusedlocationproviderapi

I have been working on utilizing the FusedLocationProviderApi in my android application, however whenever I create the GoogleApiClient as follows:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
```

The fine location icon in the notification bar turns on before I even call connect on the the client. The contexts I tried this with included activity and application scoped contexts, both yielded the same result.

My problem is that this seems to be keeping the phone awake wasting battery for no reason. The documentation does not mention anything regarding this as far as I could tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved, there was some interaction going on between the GoogleApiClient and a GoogleMap element. The GPS radio being turned on was coming from the map element but was triggered by the creation of the GoogleApiClient.